# Min and max of an IntStream with just one iteration

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

The `IntStream` has `min()` and `max()` methods for finding the corresponding values within a stream of integers. Is it possible to get the same information (min + max) with just one iteration?

Comment: Look at `IntSummaryStatistics`. There is a terminal operation on an `IntStream` that gives you one.

Comment: Many thx! Please provide your suggestion as an answer, not as a comment, so I can accept it